# How to get rid of the warning "cannot resolve symbole 'id/andr'" for ExpandableListView"

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.2

An app uses [ExpandableListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity), and the usage of ExpandableListView is standard based on the document:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
</ExpandableListView>
```

Android Studio 3.2 has the following warning:
[image]

How can I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a typo. Change it to:

```
"@android:id/empty"
```

and

```
"@android:id/list"
```

See also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id **"@android:id/list"** (or R.id.list
>   if it's in code)

Comment: Thank you.  "@android:id/list" did it.  I do not know how to use "@android:id/empty".  Should it be used for the same ExpandableListView?

Comment: @Hong `@id/android:list` is obviously no valid syntax, so I would say yes.

Comment: I added @android:id/empty to the same ExpandableListView in addition to "@android:id/list", but got error "Duplicate attribute id".

Comment: @Hong You can't add two ids to one view.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your answer.  What do you mean by " Change it to:

"@android:id/empty"
and

"@android:id/list""?

Comment: @Hong It means that it is presumably wrong in this example. `android:id="@id/android:list"` should be `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Very sorry for being so slow in understanding you.  How should I follow the first part of your answer: "Change it to:

"@android:id/empty""  I have done the second part that seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is ( id="@id/android:list")

give it an normal id ( @+id/androidlist )
and handle it in your code

but if you learn how to work with ExpandableListView
I prefer this link tutorial for you [ExpandableListView Link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

GL sir

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help.  The usage is copied from the official document for ExpandableListActivity as indicated in my original post.  Adding "+" does not solve the problem.   ExpandableListActivity has been working very well so far, so I do not plan to change it.  I just want to get rid of the warning.